# Im trying to install tensorflow on Anaconda that supports python 2.7 and I'm stuck

Tags: error-handling, tensorflow, installation, anaconda

Im trying to install tensorflow on Anaconda that supports python 2.7, I did as the manual given on the tensorflow homepage told me to do, and this error occurs every time.

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python 2.7*
  - tensorflow -> protobuf ==3.1.0 -> python 3.5*
Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

could you help me out??

and this is my conda info

conda info
Current conda install:

```
           platform : win-64
      conda version : 4.3.7
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.7
conda-build version : 2.0.2
     python version : 2.7.12.final.0
   requests version : 2.12.4
   root environment : C:\Users\sml\Anaconda2  (writable)
default environment : C:\Users\sml\Anaconda2\envs\tensoflow
   envs directories : C:\Users\sml\Anaconda2\envs
      package cache : C:\Users\sml\Anaconda2\pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
        config file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.7 requests/2.12.4 CPython/2.7.12 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.14393
```

Comment: Oh and this is my conda info

Comment: Which channel are you getting tensorflow from? conda-forge only offers python3.5 for windows

Comment: oh..I see I didn't know that

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, on Microsoft Windows TensorFlow only runs on Python 3.5 64-bit.

Python 2.7 is unsupported because TensorFlow uses many C++11 features (e.g., `auto`), but [the version of the Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler used for Python 2.7  is 2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20170304154430/https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/windows.html#compiling-python-on-windows).