# Installing tensorflow CPU with windows 10 anaconda python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, anaconda

I am using anaconda, python 2.7, windows 10. I would like to install tensorflow with conda. However, I am having this error:

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\cenk>conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow python=2.7
Fetching package metadata ...............
Solving package specifications: .


UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - python 2.7*
  - tensorflow -> protobuf ==3.1.0 -> python 3.4*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Comment: Tensorflow is only available from conda-forge on Windows for Python 3.5. See here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow/files?sort=basename&sort_order=desc

Comment: duplicate of [Im trying to install tensorflow on Anaconda that supports python 2.7 and I'm stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41799593/395857)

Comment: After trying to install tensorflow for about 10 hours, I have found a clear explanation that works: [link](https://gettocode.com/2016/12/02/keras-on-theano-and-tensorflow-on-windows-and-linux/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow only supports Python 3.5 64-bit on Windows. 
You need the corresponding Anaconda distribution.

Make sure to create an environment for `Python=3.5` as Anaconda recently upgraded their distribution from `3.5` to `3.6` which is also not supported with a pre-build binary yet on Windows (i.e. you need to build TensorFlow from source to use Python 3.6 on Windows).

As a side note the conda package is not official so I'd recommend using the [wheel provided on TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows#installing_with_anaconda). As an alternative you can install with the PYPI packages through `pip install tensorflow`.

For complete information on TensorFlow installation on Windows please [see here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows).